# warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast, sorting arguments

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I know this was asked a few times, but I still do not fully understand the issue.
I have an assigment where I need to save and sort the arguments.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

    int c;
    char* s = malloc(argc * sizeof(char));

    extern char *optarg;


    extern int optind;
    extern int optopt;

    while ( (c = getopt(argc, argv, ":adh")) != -1) {
        s[argc] = argv;
        switch (c) {
            case 'a': printf("a\n");
                      break;
            case 'd': printf("d\n");
                      break;
            case 'h': printf("h\n");
                      break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I know that it has something to do with me saving a pointer to an integer or not doing it.

`char* argv[]` is what? An array of pointers?
And `s` is only an array of chars?

Comment: `char* s = malloc(argc * sizeof(char));` -> `char **s = malloc(argc * sizeof(char *));`

Comment: also `s[argc]` writes out of bounds

Comment: Why would s[argc] go out of bounds if you set it to be the size of argc?

Comment: arrays go from 0 to n-1, so array[n] is always out of bounds.

Answer (score 0):

> `char* argv[]` is what? An array of pointers?

When such a declaration appears in a function prototype, as in your code, it is equivalent to `char **argv`.  That's a pointer to a pointer to `char`.  In this particular case, the pointed-to pointer is the first element of an array of pointers.

> And s is only an array of
>   chars?

As you have declared an initialized it, `s` is a pointer to `char`, and in particular, it points to the first `char` in a dynamically allocated block.  You can use the block via `s` as if it were an array of `char`, but it is not technically an array, and `s` *definitely* is not an array.  Although related, pointers and arrays are very different things.

The compiler should have told you at least on which line the error occurs, but you did not pass that information on to us.  Nevertheless, I think I can guess.  This line ...

```
s[argc] = argv;
```

... is nonsense.  Since `s` is a pointer to `char`, `s[argc]` designates one `char` (and in C, `char` is among the integer data types).  On the other hand, `argv` is a pointer (to pointer to `char`).  Although C permits pointers to be converted to integers, it is rarely useful to do so, and anyway, a conforming program must use a cast to perform such a conversion.  Since you don't actually use `s` for anything, your best bet is probably to just remove that line.

For what it's worth, if you wanted to set `s` to point to one of the command line arguments, say the second, the syntax would be

```
s = argv[2];
```

(The zeroth element of `argv` is conventionally the name of the program; the arguments start at index 1.)  But if you intend to do that then you don't need to `malloc()` any memory for `s`; whatever you do allocate for it is leaked when you assign a new value to it.

Comment: Yes that line was/is the issue.
So s is not a dynamic array?
I need to insert n amount of command line arguments into it and then sort it.
s[2] = argv[2] would not save the second argument into the second reserved space in s?

Comment: @AlešKovačič, C does not have "dynamic arrays" *as such*, but like I said, if you dynamically allocate a block of memory and assign `s` to point to it then you can use that memory, via pointer `s`, as if it were an array.  That is admittedly a fine distinction; and you probably do not need to pay too much attention to the difference except around pedants like me.

Comment: In any event, an assignment such as `s[2] = argv[2]` is still wrong (requires a cast, and does not serve your purpose) because `s` is a pointer to `char`, whereas `argv` is a pointer to *pointer to* `char`.  Just as before, you have mismatching levels of indirection.  If that's the kind of thing you want to do then you should declare `s` as `char **s`, and you allocate enough space.  This is the way I would probably write it: `char **s = malloc(argc * sizeof(*s));`.

Answer (score 0):

`char *argv[]` is a pointer to an array of strings.  AKA `char **argv`
`int argc` is an integer count of the number of strings on the command line, including exe name.

Note also that the length of each string in `argv[]` has nothing to do with the value of argc.  The strings can be as short as two characters, such as `a\0` or as long as (or longer than) 1000 characters.

So the statement `char* s = malloc(argc * sizeof(char));` will not do what you are thinking it will do.
First it is the form of an expression that will create some space for only one string, not `argc` of them.
Second, if your command line included 3 item, ( `argc == 3` ) and one of the arguments was a string of length 9, say `arguments`, then your `malloc` statement would create space for 1 string, with only 3 characters.  Not big enough to contain the string `arguments\0', not to mention the other two.

Use something like the following to determine the length of the longest of the `argc` strings:

```
int len = 0, lenKeep = 0;
for(i=0;i<argc;i++)
{
    len = strlen(argv[i] > len)
    if(len > lenKeep) lenKeep = len;
}
```

Now,  `lenKeep + 1` has been established as the length needed to contain the longest string (+ 1 for the NULL character, which `strlen(...)` does not include in its count.).  This can be used, along with knowing the number of strings, `argc`,   to allocate memory for each of them.

For example:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
...
   char **string = Create2DStr(argc, lenKeep + 1);//will create space
                                                  //sufficient to contain
                                                  //strings of your command line
...
}
```

Where `Create2DStr(...)` could be defined as:

```
char ** Create2DStr(ssize_t numStrings, ssize_t maxStrLen)
{
    int i;
    char **a = {0};
    a = calloc(numStrings, sizeof(char *));
    for(i=0;i<numStrings; i++)
    {
      a[i] = calloc(maxStrLen + 1, 1);
    }
    return a;
}
```